# The most efficient way to remove first N elements in a list?

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to remove the first n elements from a list of objects in Python 2.7. Is there an easy way, without using loops?

Comment: `x.pop(5)`, `del x[5]` or `x.remove("cow")`. The first two removes by index and the later removes by search criteria. The second can be combined by doing `del x[2:5]` which delites indexes 2-5

Comment: why the 5? if i have for example [a,b,c,d,e,f,g...z] and want to keep only [f,g...z]?

Comment: Then you'd want to do `pos = x.index("f"); end = x.index("z"); del x[pos:end]` You'd have to take in to account that `z` might exist before `f` and use `pos` as a starting poiint when searching for `z` etc but you get the idea.

Comment: maybe you want list[n:]

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use list slicing to archive your goal.

Remove the first 5 elements:

```
n = 5
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
newlist = mylist[n:]
print newlist
```

Outputs:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or `del` if you only want to use one list:

```
n = 5
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
del mylist[:n]
print mylist
```

Outputs:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 60):

Python lists were not made to operate on the beginning of the list and are very ineffective at this operation.

While you can write

```
mylist = [1, 2 ,3 ,4]
mylist.pop(0)
```

It's **very** inefficient.

---

If you only want to delete items from your list, you can do this with `del`:

```
del mylist[:n]
```

Which is also really fast:

```
In [34]: %%timeit
help=range(10000)
while help:
    del help[:1000]
   ....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 161 µs per loop
```

---

If you need to obtain elements from the beginning of the list, you should use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) by Raymond Hettinger and its [`popleft()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) method.

```
from collections import deque

deque(['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])

>>> d.pop()                          # return and remove the rightmost item
'j'
>>> d.popleft()                      # return and remove the leftmost item
'f'
```

A comparison:

### list + pop(0)

```
In [30]: %%timeit
   ....: help=range(10000)
   ....: while help:
   ....:     help.pop(0)
   ....:
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop
```

### deque + popleft()

```
In [33]: %%timeit
help=deque(range(10000))
while help:
    help.popleft()
   ....:
1000 loops, best of 3: 812 µs per loop
```

Comment: using del mylist[:n] it's still inefficient ?

Comment: I'm curious: how can `pop` be efficient if `list` is array backed? https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @RedVelvet: Yes. Nevertheless, regarding `deque` vs `list` keep in mind, that deque does not have all features which `list` have. on bigger shifts (1 million rows) I found `del mylist[1000000:]` is around the same execution as `deque.popleft()` for all the rows.. So it depends on your use case.

Comment: wow, is it actually in the specs that you can iterate over a deque while you're calling `popleft()` on it?

Answer (score 5):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
del l[0:3] # Here 3 specifies the number of items to be deleted.
```

This is the code if you want to delete a number of items from the list. You might as well skip the zero before the colon. It does not have that importance. This might do as well.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
del l[:3] # Here 3 specifies the number of items to be deleted.
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient approach, memory-wise and complexity-wise, is this:

```
popped_items = lst[:n]
del lst[:n]
```

It allows you to first obtain the first n items and only allocate the space for them. And then, you delete them from the initial list, which is also fast.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this code:

```
del x[:N]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this list:

```py
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And you want to remove the `x` last elements and store them in another list

```py
newlist = [mylist.pop() for _ in range(x)]
```

You can modify the argument you pass to pop in order to remove elements from the beginning

```py
newlist = [mylist.pop(0) for _ in range(x)]
```

Or leave the first element and remove `x` elements after

```py
newlist = [mylist.pop(1) for _ in range(x)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
l = [5,1,4,2,3,6]
```

Sort the list from smallest to largest

```
l.sort()
```

Remove the first 2 items in the list

```
for _ in range(2)
    l.remove(l[0])
```

Print the list

```
print(l)
```